# Jquery : Select option has "different" value in jquery script and actual html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to update/save dynamically created html objects using jquery. But in one particular scenario value printed in console and actual html have different values.

Here is the Jquery code.

```
var span = $(this).children('span').first();    
var choice = span.children('label').eq(1).next('select').val();
console.log(choice);
console.log($(this).html());
```

The output(truncated) in console looks like this.

```
Voicemail
....
<label for="id_00-choices">Choices</label> : <select name="00-choices" id="id_00-choices"> <option value="Voicemail">Voicemail</option> <option value="Phone" selected="selected">Phone</option> <option value="Conference">Conference</option> </select> 
....
```

As is obvious, in html "Phone" is the selected option, but Jquery (correctly) tells me "Voicemail" is the selected option, which I selected manually.

I'm using latest jquery, and I'm using Jquery Dialog for my application. Why am I getting different values, and secondly, can I force the html to change the value of selected option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("select").val()` gets currently selected value (you said that you selected `Voicemail` option manually).

If you want to get an option with `selected` attributed use:

```
var choice = span.children('label').eq(1).next('select').find("option[selected]").val();
```

Comment: Oh. How do I change the "selected" value in html?

Comment: you really want to do that? what's the problem with default behavior?

Comment: Well I researched the issue a bit more. I'm using Jquery Dialog, and due to some bug/odd behavior, whenever I update the Dialog box, "select" options donot published into the form. Hence I always end up with "default" choice. Text boxes etc work just fine. So I was thinking for forcing the html to take the chosen value. So how do I do that?

Comment: `$("select").val()` gets chosen option or I don't understand you

Comment: $("select").val() is fine as far as jquery is concerned. Jquery Dialog plugin creates in-memory objects of given "div". But as soon as I try to convert those objects back to actual html(so as to POST back to server), I lose the "select" element information. Some bug I guess. So the workaround is possibly to just force change directly in html. I accomplished that with `$('select').find("option[selected]").val(choice);` . Its a bad hack, but it works for me for the time being.